# Make Google Pay require unlocking for NFC payment?

Tags: security, google-pay

I have installed Google Pay and NFC credit card payment is neat. However, I don't feel safe about it. What if someone snatches my phone, then pays with it before I notice, or after I notice but before I can call my bank to stop the credit card tied to the account?

As things go now, payment up to 30 Euro (I am in Ireland) work without unlocking the phone, just by waking it up with the power button.

Is it possible to set Google Pay to work with NFC only when the phone is unlocked? In this way, if the phone is snatchedm at least it will take the thueves some time to find my pattern...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I figured out can be done, is to make a job on the phone which would disable NFC whenever the phone is locked and enable it when the phone is unlocked.

I read that it could be done with Tasker but it requires assigning some extra permissions with developer tools (but it doesn't require rooting the phone).

Comment: Hi,  I did not go through the process,  but when you install tasker and try to use the NFC toggle it points you to the instruction how to make it work. Then you just create a rule

Comment: [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en&gl=US) is another such app people use for this.